# Is there a python function/library to create a field from gridded data?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have data that is specified on a 3D grid, for example:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.random.rand(4, 4, 4)
```

Is there a way to get an (interpolated) value of this data for an *arbitrary* point (that is, not on the grid)?  The [interpolation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html) doc shows you can display such data, but I don't know how to get the *value* f(arbitrary_point).  Thanks.

Comment: `scipy` has lots of interpolation goodies.  I might look there.  [one example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html#scipy.interpolate.interpn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scipy.interpolate.griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) allows N-dimensional interpolation.  Below is a 3D example where I've evaluated f(r) = cos(r)^2 on a grid, then interpolated the grid data.  Either the grid data or interpolated data can be plotted below to verify that the interpolation works correctly:

```
%matplotlib inline
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from math import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define grid points and f(r) = cos^2(r) and format for interpolation: 
N = 10;
x_range, y_range, z_range = [np.linspace(0,pi,N), np.linspace(0,pi,N), np.linspace(0,pi,N)];
x_grid,y_grid,z_grid = np.meshgrid(x_range,y_range,z_range);
xi, yi, zi = x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel(), z_grid.ravel();
xi, yi, zi = xi[:], yi[:], zi[:];
f = np.cos((xi**2 + yi**2 + zi**2)**(1/2))**2;
points = np.dstack([xi, yi, zi]);
points = points[0,:,:];

#create random points and interpolate f(r):
[x_rand, y_rand, z_rand] = [pi*np.random.rand(N**3), pi*np.random.rand(N**3), pi*np.random.rand(N**3)]
random_points = np.dstack([x_rand, y_rand, z_rand])
random_points = random_points[0,:,:]

f_interpolated = interpolate.griddata(points, f, random_points, method='linear');

#PLOT THE RESULTS: 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

#_____________PLOT GRID OR INTERPOLATED DATA ______________
surf = ax.scatter(xi,yi,zi,c=f,s=20,alpha=.8)
surf = ax.scatter(x_rand,y_rand,z_rand,c=f_interpolated)

fig.colorbar(surf, aspect=16)

plt.show()
```